# Update SQL error

Tags: sql

I have a trigger that can be insert or update to another table.

Before I add update, the trigger is functional, after I add update, there is an error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Can you help me on this?

```
UPDATE 
    OLT_Balance_Update
SET 
    StartOfDayBalance = 
       (SELECT dbo.OLT_Cash_Posting.ClientNo, 
               ROUND(dbo.OLT_ArAp.NetArAp, 0) + ISNULL(dbo.OLT_Cash_Posting.Amount, 0) + ISNULL(dbo.interface_rlf_deposits.PortoQuantity * dbo.interface_rlf_deposits.PortoAverage, 0) + ISNULL(dbo.OLT_ArAp.InvestorBAC, 0) AS StartOfDayBalance
        FROM  dbo.OLT_Cash_Posting 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OLT_Client ON dbo.OLT_Cash_Posting.ClientNo = dbo.OLT_Client.ClientNo 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OLT_ArAp ON dbo.OLT_Cash_Posting.clientno = dbo.OLT_ArAp.ClAcNo 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.interface_rlf_deposits ON dbo.OLT_Client.ClientNo = dbo.interface_rlf_deposits.clAcno)
        WHERE 
              Clientno IN (SELECT P.ClientNo 
                           FROM  OLT_Balance_Update P, inserted I  
                           WHERE P.ClientNo = I.ClientNo)
```

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL Server? You should always tag your SQL questions with the relevant database.

Comment: You **cannot** have a `SET StartOfDayBalance = ` and then return **multiple columns** from that `SELECT` - that's your core problem. Fix this, and you should be fine.

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

multiple values returning against your SET StartOfDayBalance statement

```
UPDATE OLT_Balance_Update
SET StartOfDayBalance =  ROUND(dbo.OLT_ArAp.NetArAp, 0) + ISNULL(dbo.OLT_Cash_Posting.Amount, 0) + ISNULL(dbo.interface_rlf_deposits.PortoQuantity * dbo.interface_rlf_deposits.PortoAverage, 0) + ISNULL(dbo.OLT_ArAp.InvestorBAC, 0)
FROM  dbo.OLT_Cash_Posting 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OLT_Client 
    ON dbo.OLT_Cash_Posting.ClientNo = dbo.OLT_Client.ClientNo 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OLT_ArAp 
    ON dbo.OLT_Cash_Posting.clientno = dbo.OLT_ArAp.ClAcNo 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.interface_rlf_deposits 
    ON dbo.OLT_Client.ClientNo = dbo.interface_rlf_deposits.clAcno
WHERE Clientno IN 
(SELECT P.ClientNo FROM  OLT_Balance_Update P join inserted I on P.ClientNo = I.ClientNo)
```